# What is meant by "extending httpd" in the context of mod_python?

Tags: python, wsgi

In [a highly-upvoted comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421023/343302) two statements are made:

> mod_wsgi is for running web apps.

‎

> mod_python is for extending httpd.

I suppose that the first statement refers to interactive websites as web-apps. But what does the second statement mean? `httpd` is very commonly the Apache daemon which serves the website. How is Apache extended? How is this different than "serving a web app"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_python can be used to *write Apache extensions in general*.

Extensions like `mod_rewrite` (albeit with clunkier configuration) could be written with `mod_python`; it's not specific to serving web services written in Python, but can be used to modify Apache behaviors even in conjunction with other app servers or content sources.

The [original paper introducing mod_python](http://modpython.org/python10/) goes into this in some detail: A handler written in mod_python can take some action on a request, and then decline to act as a terminal handler, letting other Apache modules (including, eventually, the static handler) decide what to return.

Comment: Thank you! With the example given, the statement becomes clear.

Comment: One can use mod_wsgi to extend some parts of Apache as well. In fact the main reason people previously used mod_python was to implement custom authentication mechanisms. One can do that with mod_wsgi as well and it actually does it in a better way, properly hooking into Apache's authentication provider hooks. There isn't really much beyond that that saw a lot of use as far as extending Apache with Python. Everything else was simply Python web applications.

Answer (score -2):

It just means Apache is then able to interpret Python scripts and replace the python with HTML/js to serve to the client. Allows it to serve "web apps" written in Python

Comment: This answer is flatly wrong; mod_python is far more flexible than this, and can intercept and interact with requests that it isn't providing body content for itself. (Indeed, otherwise the distinction would make no sense -- mod_wsgi can provide body content serving webapps in Python as well).